# How Can I Add Image or Icon Submenu Dynamically

Tags: android, submenu

I'm trying to chose any icon or image for my submenu. I'm creating my submenu with this code. It creates submenu but it does not show any icon or image.

```
    final SubMenu subMenu = menu.addSubMenu("SubMenu Title");
    for (int i = 0; i < sayacim; i++) {
        subMenu.add(bilgiler[i].toString());
        subMenu.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer_home);
    }
```

What do I need to do to show the icon?

Actually if I solve this problem then after that I will make a code for loading image from internet. If you have any idea for this you can write here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to recreate the overflow menu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // recreate tree dots sub menu
    final SubMenu subMenu = menu.addSubMenu(null);
    subMenu.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_more_white_24px);
    subMenu.getItem().setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    // add items in you new sub menu
    for (MenuData menuData : menuDataList) {
        final MenuItem item = subMenu.add(
            Menu.NONE,
            menuData.id(),
            Menu.NONE,
            menuData.title()
        );
        item.setIcon(menuData.icon());
    }
    return true;
}
```